Assigning application permissions to users/groups and other principals in Entra ID
I have two application and principal pairs in Entra ID. One of my applications exposes a number of roles, some are intended for users and groups, while others are appplication-only.
When I assign users and groups, I have full control of this if I own the service principal that exposes  the roles:

However, when I want to grant a permission to another service principal, I need a Global Admin (or less?) to approve this permission:

This behaviour is a hurdle for anyone working with application permissions. How come that I, the owner of both applications and service principals involved in the permission, is not the one deciding if this can be approved or not? This means that anyone can request roles for my APIs, and then someone approves it without my knowledge. If I own the application exposing the role, I would assume I would be the one approving it.
I realize this is a tenant setting, and I do not have access to this in the tenant where the screenshots are from. I do however have my own tenant where I could experiment, but I am not sure at all what I am looking for.
I am mainly curious about how I should reason about this.
Are there ways to improve this workflow for developers?
What settings am I looking for?
How come it works like this for principals? I assume there is good reason for it, just that I don't understand it.


Note that: To grant admin consent to the API permissions added to the Microsoft Entra ID application either Privileged Role Administrator or Cloud Application Administrator or Application Administrator roles is required. Refer this MsDoc


If you are the owner of a service principal, you have the ability to assign roles directly to users and groups without requiring additional approval.
This is because user roles typically do not involve elevated permissions or broad access scopes, and therefore do not pose a significant security risk. This level of control is straightforward and allows you to manage user roles efficiently and effectively.
But to grant admin consent, you must require any elevated role as mentioned.

If you want users to send the approve request, you can try doing the below:
Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions -> Set Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to​ as YES and add user who can approve request

I created a Microsoft Entra ID application and added app role:

For sample, used the below endpoint to authorize users
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirectURL
&response_mode=query
&scope=scope
&state=12345

When I tried to sign in, the user gets Approval required screen like below:

The reviewer must have at least cloud administrator role to approve the request:
Go to Enterprise applications -> Activity -> Select Admin consent requests -> My Pending tab

Click on Review permissions and consent and approve request.
Now I signed in with the same user and the user is able to login successfully:


Application permissions often grant wide-ranging access to APIs and data within the tenant.
Hence Admin consent is necessary for application permissions to ensure that there is a process in place to review and approve the access being requested.
This helps ensure that the access is necessary and appropriate, and that only authorized applications/users have access to the requested resources.

Reference:
Overview of permissions and consent in the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft


Application permissions often grant wide-ranging access to APIs and data within the tenant.

I understand if this would be Graph permissions or something not exposed by a single-tenant application. But my role might as well be applicable to applications, users and groups.

But still it needs admin consent

So basically it’s a security measure with no workarounds. I just find it a bit odd, because the person reviewing the request doesn’t necessarily know the implications of approving said request. Especially for roles that were created by developers building an application

Yeah you are right. You can assing cloud admin role to approve requests too if its feasible in your environment
